# Faster querying with temp table creation (SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql, temp-tables

I've noticed that when I have a complex query, if I ***select into*** a temp table or create a new table from the query, the query seems faster to process then if I did not. I'm wondering if anyone else has noticed this effect, and could provide a reason for it?

Comment: Not really answerable without more details but some possible suggestions [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765738/how-can-i-force-a-subquery-to-behave-like-a-temp-table)  if you are talking about breaking up the query with `#temp` tables.

Comment: It is. http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/115/posts/11142/select-into-is-faster-than-create-amp-insert.aspx

Comment: @YuriyGalanter - The OP should supply an example of what they mean IMO.

Comment: Are you talking about select into being faster than not using any form of extra table at all? Or just that select into is faster than create temp table + insert?